# Battery consumption

Tags: batteries

I'm fixing an old radio (69') and in the specifications says that the battery consumption is 18m/a MW and LW, 21m/a VHF. Do you know what exactly the m/a unit is? Is it milliampers?

Comment: yes, milliampere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to hazard a bet, I'd say that's the only likely interpretation of it. What else could it mean? The voltage is not likely to be different, but the current could change with different bands.